# Multiple params in Java Rest API JAX-RS - GET Method

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I want to pass multiple parameters into my method. How do I do this? I want the url to look like this http://host/one/two/three/four

I have the below code so far

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/{one,two,three}") 

public List<Person> getPeople(@PathParam ("one") String one, @PathParam ("two") String two, @PathParam ("three") String three){
   String one = one; 
   String two = two; 
   String three = three;

}
```

Is this the right syntax for grabbing the params and passing it to my method? I've seen some regular expressions used in the @Path but I don't understand it. I honestly really just want to be able to grab the parameters and put them in a variable if possible.

Comment: Are you asking for an indeterminate number of parameters or is there a fixed number?  You show through 3 in your example, but through 4 in your example url.

Answer (score 5):

**Fixed number** of path parameters:

```java
@GET
@Path("/{one}/{two}/{three}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response foo(@PathParam("one") String one,
                    @PathParam("two") String two,
                    @PathParam("three") String three) {

    ...
}
```

**Variable number** of path parameters:

```java
@GET
@Path("/{path: .+}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response foo(@PathParam("path") String path) {

    String[] paths = path.split("/");

    ...
}
```

Comment: @Luke Check the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2193).